# adding a icon and a shortcut to Enterprise Architect Addin

Tags: python-2.7, add-in, enterprise-architect

I have created an Addin(Extension) for Enterprise Architect. And it appears under extensions when i right click on any model element. Now i want to have an custom icon and an custom shortcut key for the same. Also i want to do it in my program which registers this Addin to Enterprise Architect. I have written this Addin in Python 2.7. The Image for my Addin is Below, Also you can see some below menu items having icons and shortcuts

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [link](http://community.sparxsystems.com/community-resources/805-triggering-add-in-functionality-with-custom-hotkeys-in-enterprise-architect) enables to invoke your addin by key combination.

Easy to implement!